# How to enumerate a dictionary shorthanded (or convert all keys type of a dictionary) in Swift?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary with type `[MyKeys : Any]`. Where `MyKeys` is an `Enum` with `String` as its `rawValue`. I need to convert that key type to a `String`. Or rather make a new dictionary out of that current dictionary with type `[String : Any]`.

So far I have this code I played on Playground. It works but I need a more efficient (if there's any) and a shorter one.

```
import UIKit

enum MyKey: String {
    case aaa = "lalal"
}

func lolo(_ keyDic: [MyKey : Any]) {
    var finalDic = [String : Any]()
    for keyDic in keyDic.enumerated() {
        let key = keyDic.element.key
        let val = keyDic.element.value
        finalDic[key.rawValue] = val
    }

    finally(finalDic)
}

func finally(_ dic: [String : Any]) {
    print(dic)
}

lolo([MyKey.aaa : 123])
```

**UPDATE:**

I found a better way while I was waiting for some answers:

```
var finalDic = [String : Any]()
keyDic.enumerated().map{( finalDic[$0.element.key.rawValue] = $0.element.value )}
finally(finalDic)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your function more generic (it will work on any `Dictionary` whose key is an `enum` with `String` raw value) and shorter (not necessarily more efficient though) using below function:

```
extension Dictionary where Key: RawRepresentable, Key.RawValue: Hashable {
    func enumKeyToStringKey() -> [Key.RawValue: Value] {
        return self.reduce(into: [Key.RawValue:Value](), { currentResult, keyValue in
            currentResult[keyValue.key.rawValue] = keyValue.value
        })
    }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
[MyKey.aaa : 123].enumKeyToStringKey()
```

Comment: Or `Key.RawValue: Hashable` to make it less restrictive.

Comment: Thanks guys! Although both are correct and definitely better than the two ways/codes I posted on my question, I'm choosing David's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your loop can be simplified to

```
for (key, value) in keyDic {
    finalDic[key.rawValue] = value
}
```

A not necessarily more efficient, but shorter and simpler approach is:

```
let dict = [MyKey.aaa : 123]
let newDict = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: dict.map { ($0.key.rawValue, $0.value )})
print(newDict) // "lalal": 123]
```

The original dictionary is mapped to a sequence of transformed key/value
pairs, from which the new dictionary is instantiated.